# Pivot Table Calculated Field to Avg the Sums totaled

Tags: sum, pivot-table, average, calculated-field

[Need this to average = 7.41](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GAOP.png)

[But this happens when I use AVG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6McgH.png)

I am trying to calculate the daily average of each employee based on the number of days worked.

I already used a pivot table to calculate the daily total hours of each employee per day but I cannot figure out how to get the pivot table to display the average work day. When I alter the field settings, it averages the source data which I do not need.

The employees worked a different # of workdays, so I need the average function to calculate based on the # of instances for each employee. When I highlight the first employees data, Excel returns an average of 7.41.

Further down the list though, there are employees with 0.00 hours for a date that is beiong calculated into the averages.

How do I get this pivot table to give me a true snapshot of the persons daily hours worked - without having to manually delete 0.00 hour instances in the source data?